# Custom Keyboard shortcuts not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04

I am following the fairly simple step to set custom keyboard for opening a specific file, following the official guidance: [Set keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en).

But its not working. Is there something obviuos I am missing here or not sure a bug exist for this in Ubuntu

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you have a valid bash command, the "Set custom shortcut" dialog does not support some features of it, among others concatenating two commands. You can have it work by specifying your command as following:

```
sh -c "cd /home... && libreoffice ..."
```

Here, you launch the shell and pass a command to it as an argument.