# Custom keyboard shortcuts not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

For some reasons custom keyboard shortcuts don't work on my machine. I tried all sort of things but when I press the corresponding hotkey nothing happens.

Built-in shortcuts such as ctr+alt+t or ctr+c/ctr+v work just fine though.

At first, it seemed some people had already encountered the exact same problem before so I was quite hopeful to solve this quickly. (cf for instance [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182972/custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-terminal-command-htop-not-working) or [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262517/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04))

But ultimately none of the provided solutions worked so it seems my problem come from something else.

What I've tried so far:

- I tried different types of commands. Here are some of them:

  - firefox
  - bash
  - bash -c 'sleep 0.3 && xdotool key U00e1'
  - gnome-terminal -- htop
  - sh -c "cd ~/Documents && gedit test.txt"

It is worth mentioning that all those commands work in terminal

- I tried different type of hotkeys (ctr+alt+a, ctr+alt+i, ctr+o, ctr+shift+d, ctr+alt+d,ctr+super+del...)
- I tried to close all my programs (browser, spotify, IDE etc.) in case the shortcuts were captured by one of them.
- tried to debug using:

  xev | sed -n 's/^.*state ([0-9].*), keycode *([0-9]+) *(.*), .*$/keycode \2 = \3, state = \1/p

as suggested in another post but what I could only derive from this was that my keyboard keys are well detected by my computer.

Where I feel super frustrated is the fact I haven't found a way to see what happens under the hood so that I could debug it somehow. ATM, it really feels just like a black box to me, hope you can help me to see through it more clearly.

Here are a couple of screenshots to illustrate my problem and make it more concrete:
[image: list of custom keyboard shortcuts]
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]
[image: Example 4]

Many thanks in advance for your help!