touchpad stays on despite being turned off in settings ubuntu 24.04
Hi so having a weird issue. I am on a Lenova Yoga7i it ran windows 10 for many years. But now i have ubuntu 24.04 and having the issue in the subject header.
It appears all of the settings for the touchpad do not do anything- IE i turn the touchpad off while typing- does nothing. Turn the whole touch pad off- does nothing. But then randomly the touch pad is off- but then it randomly turns on again even though the settings say it is off.
While ideally i would like to have the ability to turn the pad off and on, I also would settle with just disabling it all together if not easier option as it makes typing etc verrrry difficult.
thank you!

Map a key to a script that toggels on/off the touchpad.
Thanks to:
article https://www.baeldung.com/linux/enable-disable-touchpad
ask blog: https://askubuntu.com/a/1262603/1744900
and GPT providing script:
#!/bin/bash

# save this script under e.g. ~/Tools/TP-device.sh
# Check the current state of the touchpad
touchpad_state=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events)

# Toggle the state
if [ "$touchpad_state" = "'enabled'" ]; then
    echo "Touchpad is currently enabled. Disabling it..."
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events disabled
    echo "Touchpad disabled."
else
    echo "Touchpad is currently disabled. Enabling it..."
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled
    echo "Touchpad enabled."
fi

you can now create in Setting -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts
create a shortcut that maps to script:
sh -c "~/Tools/TP-device.sh" 


thanks DaveX, unfortunatly none of that seemed to work. I put in the code above and it will report that my touchpad is off despite the touchpad still being on...
Also perhaps the most annoying part is the touchpad stays on while typing despite toggling it off while typing in system settings :(

Yes, the system setting to have the touchpad off while writing is not working for me too. That's why we need the custom shortcut to on/off the touchpad manually. The scripts above are working for me and I mapped them to the F11  Key (HP Notebook)
